# Templated class specialization with multiple arguments where one template argument is a template itself

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization

I think it is easiest to just show some code:

```
template<typename T>
struct TemplateTest { //<-- generic version
    using typeGeneric = int;
};
template<>
struct TemplateTest<std::vector<int>> { //<-- specialized with specialized version of vector
    using typeVectorInt = int;
};
template<typename T>
struct TemplateTest<std::vector<T>> { //<-- specialized with generic version of vector
    using typeVectorT = int;
};

int main (int argc, char** argv) {
    typename TemplateTest<int>::typeGeneric var1;
    typename TemplateTest<std::vector<int>>::typeVectorInt var2;
    typename TemplateTest<std::vector<char>>::typeVectorT var3;
    return 0;
}
```

This is working fine and as expected. Since I used different using-names in the different specializations there would be a compile-error if a not-expected specialization is chosen during compilation. (I did this just for this post to show the problem)

However this is not working as expected:

```
template<typename Tfirst, typename Tsecond>
struct TemplateTest { //<-- generic version
    using typeGeneric = int;
};
template<typename Tfirst>
struct TemplateTest<Tfirst, std::vector<int>> { //<-- specialized with specialized version of vector
    using typeVectorInt = int;
};
template<typename Tfirst>
template<typename T>
struct TemplateTest<Tfirst, std::vector<T>> { //<-- specialized with generic version of vector
    using typeVectorT = int;
};

int main (int argc, char** argv) {
    typename TemplateTest<int, int>::typeGeneric var1;
    typename TemplateTest<int, std::vector<int>>::typeVectorInt var2;
    typename TemplateTest<int, std::vector<char>>::typeVectorT var3;
    return 0;
}
```

var3 is the problem. The vector specialization is not working (not chosen by the compiler) and I don't know why. Can this be done and if so how?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're declaring the 2nd specialization in wrong syntax (with extraneous template parameter list); change it to

```
template<typename Tfirst, typename T>
struct TemplateTest<Tfirst, std::vector<T>> { //<-- specialized with generic version of vector
    using typeVectorT = int;
};
```